# ¿Como puedo recorrer datos desfasados?

Tags: python

Tengo este código donde, con un bucle for, recorro una lista de archivos que contienen datos de mediciones obtenidas con un Osciloscópio. Al momento de hacer la gráfica de la primer columna de mis archivos que es Tiempo Vs Voltaje éstos datos presentan un desfase. Ya que el mínimo de Voltaje tiene que estar en T=0, cosa que no ocurre, la mayoría de los mínimos caen en T = -0.30, por lo que al momento de graficarlos los datos presentan un desfase.

```py
from os import listdir
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import ascii

#En esta parte se genera un Arreglo con el nombre de todos los archivos que hay en la carpeta.
files = [f for f in listdir('/home/maza/Escritorio/osciloscopio/fuentealphatrigger19') if f.endswith('.txt')]
files.sort()

#contador para llevar un control de cuantos archivos fueron graficados
contador = 0

#con este bucle for le digo a la computadora que me analise cada uno de los archivos con datos que hay en la carpeta
for i in files:
    data = ascii.read(i, header_start=3, data_start=4)

#condicional que le dice al bucle for que no me tome los datos que estan saturados.
    if min(data['Ampl']) < -0.05:
        continue

    contador = contador + 1
    print (min(data['Ampl']))
    plt.plot(data['Time'],data['Ampl'])
    plt.xlim(-0.00000001,0.00000001)
    plt.ylim(-0.05, 0.005)

print (contador)                    
plt.show()
```

[image: Gráfico con los datos desfazados]

Answer (score 0):

Debes buscar el indice del mínimo valor en `data['Ampl']` y restar a `data['Time']` el valor de `data['Time']` en esa misma posición:

```
min_idx = data['Ampl'].index(min(data['Ampl']))
t = data['Time'] - data['Time'][min_idx]
plt.plot(t,data['Ampl'])
```